# URL length limit for google reader api

Tags: url, limit, google-reader

I am using "/reader/api/0/stream/items/ids" API to get the item ids for sources that I want.

I have quite a number of sources, so I repeated "s=" parameter to include in the api url.

However, google has given me an error of "URL is too long".

So the question is that How can I solve it so that I just use one time api call to get item ids for that many sources?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `/reader/api/0/stream/items/ids` path supports a `POST` method. This means the amount of data you could pass by using `POST` verb is much more than by using a query string and a `GET` method.

So use `https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/items/ids` URL for the post, and pass your query string as a post data. Don't forget to include [an action token](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/ActionToken)(`T`) which is required for `POST` requests.